# How to delete a row from database by position

Tags: java, android, sql, database, delete-row

I want to delete row by a position. I wrote this but it doesn't work. Now it's deleting a row by id, not by position. I don't know how to write that query.

For example, this is my table:

```
position |   name
1        |   aaaa
2        |   bbbb   
3        |   cccc 
4        |   dddd
```

Now I'm deleting row number 3. I want to get a table like this:

```
position |   name
1        |   aaaa
2        |   bbbb    
3        |   dddd
```

This is delete method from main activity class:

```
public void onClickBtnDelete(View view) {

SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = getListView()
        .getCheckedItemPositions(); 
int itemCount = getListView().getCount();
int[] tab = new int[itemCount];

for (int i = itemCount - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    tab[i] = itemCount - i;             
    if (checkedItemPositions.get(i)) { 
        adapter.remove(list.get(i));
        db.deleteMyPlace(new MyPlacesTable(tab[i]));
    }

}
```

This is my delete method from DatabaseHandler:

```
public void deleteMyPlace(MyPlacesTable myPlace) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_MY_PLACES, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(myPlace.getID()) });
        db.close();
}
```

And constructor, getter and setter:

```
public MyPlacesTable(int id){
        this._id = id;
}

public int getID(){
        return this._id;
}

public void setID(int id){
    this._id = id;
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: what does not work mean? where do you run the for-loop?

Comment: I think first get list item data at position and get unique value now try to remove related data from database from given unique value.

Comment: Look at the edited post.

Answer (score 0):

try this code for deleting the row from db.

```
 private SQLiteDatabase db;     
 db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
 db.delete("TABLE_NAME", "_id="+deleteId, null);
```

replace the deleted id to corresponding "i" values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  public static void DeleteData(SQLiteDatabase db, String TableName,String userfield,String userid) 
      {
           String table_name = TableName;
           String where =userfield + "='" +userid+"'";
           String whereArgs[] = null;
           db.delete(table_name, where, whereArgs);

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this will delete information based in the column, maybe this will assist in pragmatically finding a solution.

```
 /* Delete rows */
delete from /*table*/ where /*column*/ between 51 and 129
```